# Can't Toggle Through Images With JQuery Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to write a function that upon each button click, it changes the shape of the triangle.

I'm a novice, and I could probably do this quicker with toggle() but I want to get better at writing functions because it's holding me back. Any help would be appreciated. You don't have to give me the answer, but a point in the right direction would be so appreciated! Thank you.

I have the first two shapes but I don't know how to bring in the last two.

https://jsfiddle.net/gs0c30vd/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tri").click(function(){
        $('#triangleup').hide();
        $('#triangleright').show();

    }) ; 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple and small jQuery script can do it like below - the only requirement for this is that you add the same class to the elements (see HTML beneath):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// declare the first element in the range w. respect to the order of the HTML
var firstElement = $(".firstTriangle");
// declare the last element in the range here to reset the "loop" of elements
var lastElement = $(".lastTriangle");

$("#tri").click(function() {
  if ($(lastElement).is(":hidden")){
    $(".triangle").filter(":visible").hide().next().show();
} else {
$(lastElement).hide();
$(firstElement).show();
};
});

 // ------------------------------------------------------------
 // The original uni-directional method is above. 
 // Beneath I have added "support" for a bi-directional method; 
 // i.e. going either up or down in the HTML
 // ------------------------------------------------------------

$("#counterclockwise").click(function() {
  if ($(firstElement).is(":hidden")){
    $(".triangle").filter(":visible").hide().prev().show();    
} else {
$(firstElement).hide();
$(lastElement).show();
};
});

});
```

You can check it out in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r3zLc920/6/). 
The real **benefit** of this little method is that you dont have to declare every element in the range which you would like to show. If you apply it for a slider with a lot of images it gets tiresome to type in every element (at least in my opinion); and especially if you change some of the elements. To make this method even easier to maintain you could just use some fixed classes which you always hold as the first and last element; such as `"firstTriangle"` and `"lastTriangle"` and then adjust the variables accordingly. I've also added this approach to the script and the HTML for future reference and ease-of-use. 

However the drawbacks should also be noted:

- You must have your elements which u wish to toggle inside a container with no other siblings (such as shown in the HTML). Otherwise it will move on to other elements and showing/hiding these, thereby breaking the function.
- There can only be one direction in which you switch between the elements (downwards in the HTML document).

However, with regard to the unidirectional "drawback" you could easily reverse the function and add another button to make up for this. Such an example can be seen here: 
[Change slides/elements in both directions](https://jsfiddle.net/r3zLc920/5/).

This effectively grants you a pretty much fully functional slider.

HTML:

```
  <div class="myContainer"> 
  <div id="triangleup" class="triangle firstTriangle"></div>
  <div id="triangleright" style="display: none;" class="triangle"></div>
  <div id="triangledown" style="display: none;" class="triangle"></div>
  <div id="triangleleft" style="display: none;" class="triangle lastTriangle"></div>
  </div>

<button id="tri">Click me to change the direction of the triangle</button>

<!-- Button for changing direction beneath -->

<button id="counterclockwise">Change direction <b>counter-clockwise</b></button>
```

**Interpretation of the function:**
If the last element in the range is hidden (we're not through the range yet) then find the visible one (`.filter(":visible")`) and hide it, and afterwards find its next (`next()`) sibling and show (`show()`) this.
However, if the last Element is visible (then you are at the end of the range), manually hide this and show the first element - thereby starting the range over again.

**Note:** Pardon my lengthy answer (although that might not be a bad thing) but this was also a learning process for me as well - I wasn't even aware that a "slideshow" effectively could be made that easy with jQuery until I found the `.filter()` parameter in connection with this question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this answer, I'd love to select it as the answer but for some reason it's not working for me locally. On Jsfiddle it works fine but it's not working at all. Would you have any idea for why it's not working? I even tried copy and pasting your code, still didn't work. I'm using this version of JQuery: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js - if that makes a different, I don't know.

Comment: Could you specify how it's not working? I mean, does it work in either of the directions, does it hide/show other elements, or does there not simply not happen anything? :) Have you checked that your local HTML has the exact same classes and Id's, and have you given your HTML the classes used in the script? I just tried using jquery 3.1.1 in the fiddle and that didnt make a difference :)

Comment: @ChrisMFerguson have you checked that your HTML classes are an exact match with the ones in the script (including capitalized letters)? Otherwise try to edit the script so it matches the classes you have - it should work :)

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay. So I uploaded all of my code here, if you could take a look at it. It works once again in the JSfiddle and maybe there's a syntax/linking issue that prohibits me from running it locally, I don't know: https://jsfiddle.net/7nqqmef7/1/

Comment: No worries @chrism :) My immediate guess is that the script is simply loaded before the DOM elements are created. Therefore, try wrapping the script in a `$(document).on("ready", function () {` and see if this solves it. You're script is loaded in the `<Head>` before any of the HTML elements

Comment: Wow, I've never had this problem before and thanks for trying to help me fix this, I appreciate it. I wrapped the script but now the fiddle doesn't work and the local files don't work either, haha: https://jsfiddle.net/7nqqmef7/2/

Comment: It's probably taking too much of your time, so I went ahead and marked your answer as the correct one. But thank you for helping me so far! I know your answer works but out of inexperience I'm not able to get it working, though I like how simple your code is.

Comment: @chris No worries - I found the error, and realized that i provided you with a faulty code :) I have updated your fiddle and now it's working. You missed a `)` in the ending brackets of the ready statement. Further the code to use is `$(document).ready(function(){    });` instead of the `.on()` example i gave before. The fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7nqqmef7/3/

Comment: @chris it's actually a good idea to (almost) always wrap your jQuery in the `document ready` code, as it will make sure that your DOM elements are loaded first :) just FYI

Comment: Oh wow, that's funny because I even tried to switch on to ready, but I still missed that last parentheses haha, thank you for catching that! Yes, it does indeed work. Thank you so much for helping me out, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flag `isUp` to know the current status and negate it on every `click`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var isUp = true;
    $("#tri").click(function(){
        if (isUp) {
            $('#triangleup').hide();
            $('#triangleright').show();        
        } else {
            $('#triangleup').show();
            $('#triangleright').hide();        
        }        
        isUp = !isUp;
    }) ; 
});
```

EDIT:

I have seen you have four triangles. If you want a full rotation, then you might want to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var directions = ["up", "right", "down", "left"];
    var directionIndex = 0;
    $("#tri").click(function(){
        $("#triangle" + directions[directionIndex]).hide();
        $("#triangle" + directions[directionIndex = ((directionIndex + 1) % directions.length)]).show();
    }) ; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Switch statement to track the current position of the triangle from 0..3 like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var rot = 0
  $("#tri").click(function() {
    switch (rot) {
      case 0:
        $('#triangleup').hide();
        $('#triangleright').show();
        rot += 1;
        break;
      case 1:
        $('#triangleright').hide();
        $('#triangledown').show();
        rot += 1;
        break;
      case 2:
        $('#triangledown').hide();
        $('#triangleleft').show();
        rot += 1;
        break;
      case 3:
        $('#triangleleft').hide();
        $('#triangleup').show();
        rot = 0;
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your html looks like this

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="shape visible"></div>
    <div class="shape"></div>
    <div class="shape"></div>
    <div class="shape"></div>
</div>
```

And your css class for .shape is display:none and .visible is display:block

Than your js can be

```
$("#tri").click(function() {
     var current = $(".visible");
     var options = $("#container");
     var index = options.index(current);

     $(".visible").removeClass("visible");

     If(index<options.length -1){
          options[index + 1].addClass("visible");
     }else{
          options[0].addClass("visible");
     }
});
```

Forgive me for the typeos I did this on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var count = 0;
    $("#tri").click(function(){
    if( count == 0)
    {
        $('#triangleup').hide();
        $('#triangleright').show();
        count++;
    }
    else if(count == 1)
    {
        $('#triangleright').hide();
        $('#triangledown').show();
        count++;
    }
    else if(count == 2)
    {
        $('#triangledown').hide();
        $('#triangleleft').show();
        count++;
    }
    else
    {
        $('#triangleleft').hide();
        $('#triangleup').show();
        count = 0;
    }
    }) ; 
});
```

this is not a good way you make upon this

Comment: Thank you, this was easy to understand. Do you have any links or ideas for me to learn simple functions like this? I want to practice more. Thank you.

Comment: this is beginner level coding .. I think you should consider little more effective coding .. anyway you can see tutorials  youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a59kOE2Ma1Q&list=PL6n9fhu94yhVDV697uvHpavA3K_eWGQap  W3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/  jquery.com : https://jquery.com/  see I am suggesting you jquery instead of javascript because that is more easy and powerful

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to store the names of the shapes in an array then have some sort of counter that increases each time you click the button. The modulus/remainder from that counter as compared to the array length will enable you to loop through them.

Code example:

```
var index = 0
var shapeArr = [
  '#triangleup',
  '#triangleright',
  '#triangledown',
  '#triangleleft'
]
var len = shapeArr.length

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#tri").click(function(){
        $(shapeArr[index % len]).hide();
        $(shapeArr[++index % len]).show();
    }) ; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have an alternative solution using just a few lines of `CSS` and a small addition in your `jQuery` code. The point is to simply rotate the triangle by using `CSS` transform attribute.

**Example using jQuery**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var degrees = 0;
  $("#tri").click(function() {
    degrees = degrees + 90;
    $('#triangle').css("transform", "rotate(" + degrees + "deg)");
  });
});
```

```css
#triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="triangle"></div>
<br>
<button id="tri">Click me to change the direction of the triangle</button>
```

You can also check this out in this updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gs0c30vd/8/).

**Example using only Javascript**

```js
var degrees = 0;
var triangle = document.getElementById("triangle");

document.getElementById("tri").addEventListener("click", function() {
  degrees = degrees + 90;
  var style = triangle.style;
  style.transform = "rotate(" + degrees + "deg)";
});
```

```css
#triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="triangle"></div>
<br>
<button id="tri">Click me to change the direction of the triangle</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! May I ask why you went with Jquery version 2.1.1 and why from the Ajax/Google API? I'm just curious, thanks!

Comment: @ChrisMFerguson jQuery 2.1.1 is available in SO snippet. In the Fiddle link the above snippet works with jQuery 3.1.1

Comment: @ChrisMFerguson by the way i think this is a short answer and it covers you fully, and does not involve showing or hiding element(s).

Comment: @ChrisMFerguson i also think this is an answer that points to the right direction by using less code and do more work than the presented original fiddle.

Comment: However it doesn't really answer the topic title, stating that he wishes to toggle through **images**.

Comment: @Chri.s i did not see any image at all since it is a purely `CSS` created triangle so i really tried to fit my answer to the next request... *I'm trying to write a function that upon each button click, it changes the shape of the triangle.*, i hope i gave the OP a good answer.

Comment: You're also right that there are no images in the code - I'm just basing it on the topic of the question and the idea that being able to toggle through a range of figures/images is towards creating some sort of slideshow :) 
However, based on just rotating the triangles your answer is very good, naturally